# Microsoft Bing Map Control alternate control for Silverlight

Tags: dictionary, bing

We are using Microsoft BingMap Control in SIlverlight Application.This control End of life. so could anyone help me, which control is alternate for this control.

Thanks & Regards
Venkat

Answer (score 0):

It is recommend that you migrate to the Bing Maps V8 web control which can be developed against using JavaScript or TypeScript. It is much more powerful than the Silverlight control and has a lot more features as well. Here are some resources.

- [Bing Maps V8 Interactive SDK](http://www.bing.com/api/maps/sdk/mapcontrol/isdk)
- [Bing Maps V8 Code Samples](http://bingmapsv8samples.azurewebsites.net/)
- [Bing Maps V8 documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt712542.aspx)
- [Bing Maps V8 TypeScript Definitions](https://github.com/Microsoft/Bing-Maps-V8-TypeScript-Definitions)